# How to create the UP Arrow using only HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to create the traiangle using only HTML and CSS?

I need to create the thick triangle using only CSS

I already tried this code:

```css
.arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;

  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span class="arrow-up"></span>
```

Comment: Yeah sure, we can do that. But first, what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried using border-radious property

Comment: You can see here Example of traiangle css https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a community for free code, you should have tried atleast something and if you couldn't pull it yourself or you are stuck somewhere with the code, then come here for help/solution..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this for Up arrow. More [click Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

```css
  .arrow-up {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;

    border-bottom: 15px solid blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
```

Comment: found this very helpful. http://html-tuts.com/css-arrows-up-down-left-right-triangle/

Answer (score 2):

You can create it using `border`. check snippet below..

```css
.arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```css
.up-aerow {
    border-color: transparent transparent #000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="up-aerow"></div>
```